# How to find a View in a BridgeContext?

Tags: android, android-view

TL;DR: Is there anything in `com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext` that can substitute for `Activity#findViewById(...)`?  I've looked at [the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/7767eac3232ba2fb9828766813cdb481d6a97584/tools/layoutlib/bridge/src/com/android/layoutlib/bridge/android/BridgeContext.java), but I can't find anything.

When running on a real device, an attached view's `#getContext()` returns the `Activity`.  The view can cast it and call `#findViewById(...)` to obtain a reference to some other view.

But when running in a WYSIWYG editor, `#getContext()` returns an instance of a different class.  I'm getting `com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext`.  This class isn't part of the public API, so I'm planning to access it via reflection and degrade gracefully if the implementation changes.

If you're wondering why my view wants a reference to another view... I've created a view that appears to have a hole in it.  It works by delegating its drawing to another view.  If the view with the hole is placed on top of other views, then it appears to punch a hole through any views beneath it, all the way down to the view it's using for drawing.  It works perfectly on a real device, but it would be nice to have it also work in the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Did you try iterating over the keys of `private final HashMap<View, Object> mViewKeyMap `? It would seem that it contains all views for that `BridgeContext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I awarded the bounty to dandc87 because his answer led me to the solution.  However, the code snippet in his answer crashes with a `ClassCastException` because the root `ViewParent` is not a `View`.  The mods keep rejecting my edits, so here's the complete and correct solution:

```
private View findPeerById(int resId) {
    View root = this;
    while(root.getParent() instanceof View) {
        root = (View) root.getParent();
    }
    return root.findViewById(resId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's bad to assume that `View.getContext()`, or any other platform method that returns `Context`, can be cast directly to more concrete classes, like Activity. There exist classes like `ContextThemeWrapper` which can easily destroy your assumption.

I would recommend restructuring what you are doing so that you have a parent layout that can act as an intermediary for the hole-y View and what's below it.

Or you could have a setter which would provide the View for you.

A last option is to call `View.getParent()` a bunch of times to get the root View and call `findViewById()` on that:

```
ViewParent parent;
while(getParent() != null) {
    parent = getParent();
}
View root = (View) parent;
root.findViewById(R.id.my_view);
```

BTW, `BridgeContext` is used in the WYSIWYG in place of Activity because it only mocks the Android View/Layout/Rendering system, it doesn't emulate it completely. This can be seen in other ways like how it renders shadows or shape drawable rounded corners.

Comment: Good point about the actual class of the `Context`.  I edited your example code because the root `ViewParent` turned out not to be an instance of `View`.  My version works on a real device and may be useful to someone, but it still doesn't work in the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Wait... it *does* work in the WYSIWYG editor!  The editor in Android Studio apparently caches its classes even after you run the changed project and see your changes on a device... even after exiting and restarting AS.  You have to explicitly **clean** the AS project before the editor picks up the changed View classes.